# Asp Binding question

Tags: asp.net, binding, menuitem

Below is a some sample code I am trying to update.  The client would like to make the menu item text an AppSetting Value.  I have been able to setup the appsettings and the function to implement it.  But I am getting an error on my Bind code and wondering if anyone see something I missed.

Is it as easy as setting an ID tag for the MenuItem?  When I try to use ID it is not reconizable by visual studio in the intellisense.

Error -> The MenuItem control with a two-way databinding to field OUEntity must have an ID.

---

```
<asp:MenuItem PopOutImageUrl="" Text="Administration" Selectable="false">
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text=""></asp:MenuItem>                                                       
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text='<%# Bind("OUEntity") %>'></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>                                              
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text=""  ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="" ></asp:MenuItem>
</asp:MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to replace what you have with something like the following

Comment: Hmm... Now there is nothing being passed to the menu item for the text. There is a blank spot where the text should appear. So I don't think the eval is working. I wonder if I might need to do a little in the code behind to make sure it is filled.

What do you think?

Comment: The only time that you should use the Eval is if you are using DataBinding.  Say for example you have a asp:Repeater and the server tag is found inside the asp:Repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Eval (one way binding) instead of Bind (2 way binding). I also assume you would be refering ConfigurationManager.AppSettings while doing the binding.

That said, I had to do it on the code behind based on the url. But I don't recall if it was the asp.net Menu, or a third party one.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Now there is nothing being passed to the menu item for the text.  There is a blank spot where the text should appear.  So I don't think the eval is working.  I wonder if I might need to do a little in the code behind to make sure it is filled.

What do you think?

Comment: It was a typo.  After taking the night off and looking at it the next morning I noticed the typo on the code behind.